# PHP - Different states based on time

Tags: php, date, time

i'm currently working on a project where business are opened and closed in real time by using image sprite representations of them.

In the code below i'm setting the default timezone to GMT and the time format to 0000. When testing this is fine except for between 0000 and 0959. It appears to be ignoring the time format and not putting the leading zeros in.

Additionally, is there a more efficient way of doing the below?

Thanks in advance.

```
<?php date_default_timezone_set("Europe/London"); $time = date("Hi");?> 

.<?php if($time > 1600 && $time < 2329){echo "business1";} else{echo "business1:hover";}?> {background: url(http://website.com/business1.png) 0 -145px;}
.<?php if($time > 1600 && $time < 2329){echo "business1:hover";} else{echo "business1";}?> {background: url(http://website.com/business1.png) 0 0;}

.<?php if($time > 0800 && $time < 1659){echo "business2";} else{echo "business2:hover";}?> {background: url(http://website.com/business2.png) 0 -145px;}
.<?php if($time > 0800 && $time < 1659){echo "business2:hover";} else{echo "business2";}?> {background: url(http://website.com/business2.png) 0 0;}
```

Answer (score 1):

A literal `0800` in PHP [is understood to be an *octal* number](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.integer.php) due to the leading `0`. You should not compare times as strings to begin with. Use UNIX timestamps for time comparison:

```
$now = time();
if ($now > strtotime('16:00') ...)
```

Comment: I did this test: `$i = 0800; echo $i` and it outputs '0', but that is because '8' is invalid in octal numbers.